# JUnit's own sample tests fail?

Tags: testing, junit, sample

I just downloaded junit-4.10.jar.  According to [the JUnit FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#started_2), all you have to do is extract the jar file into a directory, and put the jar file in your classpath, and it's installed.  Then you can test the installation by running the sample tests with this command:

```
java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.tests.AllTests
```

The FAQ must be out of date though, because AllTests doesn't reside in org.junit.tests, it resides in org.junit.runners.  So this is what I get when I try to run the sample tests using AllTests in the org.junit.tests package.  Anyone know why the sample tests are failing?  Yes I checked my CLASSPATH and the junit-4.10.jar is in there.

```
C:\Users\username\Downloads\junit4.10-extracted>java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.junit.runners.AllTests
JUnit version 4.10
.E.E
Time: 0.003
There were 2 failures:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runners.AllTests)
java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:144)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:121)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:101)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:13)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:38)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:79)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:69)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:98)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:45)
2) initializationError(org.junit.runners.AllTests)
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:166)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:102)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:344)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.<init>(ParentRunner.java:74)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:13)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:38)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:98)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.<init>(Suite.java:79)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:69)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:98)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMainAndExit(JUnitCore.java:53)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:45)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 2,  Failures: 2
```

Comment: org.junit.tests.AllTests does exists - Found in its test folder(...\test\java\junit\tests\AllTests.java).

Answer (score 1):

[AllTests](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/AllTests.html) is for running JUnit 3.8 tests. If you look at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.5/org/junit/runners/AllTests.java), you can see it doesn't extend TestCase (JUnit 3.8 style) or have @Test methods (JUnit 4.0 style.)  It also doesn't have a public no arguments constructor.  Which it doesn't need to because it isn't a class you can run as a unit test.

As Shengyuan notes, check the tests folder.  The AllTests class you found would be in the source folder which means you might be in the wrong folder looking for the actual sample tests.